# Как в Angular 4 вывести данные из массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, angular2

В `client.ts` вот такая модель:

```
export class Client {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    surname: string;
    city: string;
    street: string;
    housenumber: string;
    apartment: string;
    phones: string[];
}
```

Данные вывожу вот в такую таблицу:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let client of clients | filter: searchString">
        <td>{{client.id}}</td>
        <td>{{client.name}}</td>
        <td>{{client.surname}}</td>
        <td>{{client.city}}</td>
        <td>{{client.street}}</td>
        <td>{{client.housenumber}}</td>
        <td>{{client.apartment}}</td> 
        <td>{{client.phones}}</td> 
        <td><button type="button" (click)="loadTask(client.id)">View Task</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как в angular 4 вывести массив значений `phones` в таблицу красиво?
Сейчас у меня это набор типов `Object`:

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Можно в соответствующем `td` сделать ещё один `ngFor`

Comment: @diraria а как его правильно сделать?

Comment: Что-нибудь типа `<span *ngFor='let phone of client.phones'>{{phone}}</span>`. Так каждый телефон будет обернут в `span`, если хочется без оборачивания, можно использовать `ng-container`

Comment: @diraria Тот же результат **[object Object] ** Значений не видно

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в консоль массив phones и тип первого элемента этого массива, typeof(phones[0]). Такое чувство, что в этом массиве не строки записаны

Comment: @diraria 
`{id: 3, phoneNumber: 971234441, clientId: 8}`

Comment: Отлично, видите, это не строка а объект. Поэтому нужно заменить phone на phone.phoneNumber

Comment: @diraria Спасибо. Получилось

Comment: Отлично) Пишите ответ на свой вопрос :)

Comment: @diraria ему там нужно на еще один вопрос ответ написать... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726767/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-angular-4

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, я видел) Мне казалось, что там надо написать сортировку по двум полям, а это я не знаю как сделать, а искать не захотелось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный код решил проблему `<td *ngFor='let phone of client.phones'>{{phone.phoneNumber}}</td>`