# Фильтр по двум столбцам Angular 4

Tags: angular2

В инпут ввожу строку и фильтрую по имени в таблице. Код рабочий!

```
<input type="text" name="searchString" [(ngModel)]="searchString" />
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let client of clients | filter: searchString">
    <td>{{client.id}}</td>
    <td>{{client.name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.surname}}</td>
    <td>{{client.city}}</td>
    <td>{{client.street}}</td>
    <td>{{client.housenumber}}</td>
    <td>{{client.apartment}}</td> 
    <td ><ul *ngFor='let phone of client.phones'>{{phone.phoneNumber}}</ul><br /></td> 
    <td><button type="button" (click)="loadTask(client.id)">View Task</button></td>
</tr>
```

Код в pipe такой:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(clients: any[], searchString: any): any  {        
    console.log('searchString', searchString);
    return searchString
        ? clients.filter(client => client.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1)
        : clients;
};
}
```

Как изменить pipe, чтобы фильтровалось по двум столбцам? Например, по name и surname

Comment: А кто написал код для `FilterPipe`?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Я на примере туториалов

Comment: если надо фильтровать по двум полям - фильтруй по двум, можешь два раза filter вызывать, можешь в одной функции проверить что условие выполняется или для одного поля или для другого

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Довавив `(client.name + client.city)` решило мою проблему